# inserting document into mongo shard

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Mongo java async driver v3.2 using the following test.  I can see that callback is invoked (the one registered with the insertOne call on the Mongo collection).  I can see that the test client is able to connect to the mongos process (logs attached at the end).  I do not see any documents in Mongo.  I enabled the database collection for sharding and I can run the shard status command from the mongos process as well.  Any thoughts on what I might have misconfigured in the setup?

```
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        SingleResultCallback<Void> callbackWhenFinished = new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Operation Finished!");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };
final Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));
        collection.insertOne(doc, callbackWhenFinished);
        latch.await();
```

**Mongo logs:**

```
 this host as shard shard0002, but shard name was previously initialized as shard0001" } }
2016-07-20T12:02:52.682-0400 I NETWORK  [mongosMain] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:44633 #42 (1 connection now open)
2016-07-20T12:02:52.715-0400 I NETWORK  [mongosMain] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:44635 #43 (2 connections now open)
2016-07-20T12:02:52.750-0400 I NETWORK  [conn42] end connection 127.0.0.1:44633 (1 connection now open)
2016-07-20T12:02:52.750-0400 I NETWORK  [conn43] end connection 127.0.0.1:44635 (0 connections now open)
2016-07-20T12:02:57.279-0400 I SHARDING [Balancer] caught exception while doing balance: remote client 127.0.0.1:40696 tried to initialize this host as shard shard0002, but shard name was previously initialized as shard0001
2016-07-20T12:02:57.279-0400 I SHARDING [Balancer] about to log metadata event into actionlog: { _id: "ali-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook-2016-07-20T12:02:57.279-0400-578fa0b154165752fe990d83", server: "ali-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1469030577279), what: "balancer.round", ns: "", details: { executionTimeMillis: 5, errorOccured: true, errmsg: "remote client 127.0.0.1:40696 tried to initialize this host as shard shard0002, but shard name was previously initialized as shard0001" } }
2016-07-20T12:03:07.334-0400 I SHARDING [Balancer] caught exception while doing balance: remote client 127.0.0.1:40704 tried to initialize this host as shard shard0002, but shard name was previously initialized as shard0001
2016-07-20T12:03:07.335-0400 I SHARDING [Balancer] about to log metadata event into actionlog: { _id: "ali-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook-2016-07-20T12:03:07.335-0400-578fa0bb54165752fe990d84", server: "ali-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1469030587335), what: "balancer.round", ns: "", details: { executionTimeMillis: 3, errorOccured: true, errmsg: "remote client 127.0.0.1:40704 tried to initialize this host as shard shard0002, but shard name was previously initialized as shard0001" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by ensuring the the mongo cluster (query router, cofig servers and mongo shards with replica sets) was configured correctly.  Once this was done, I could see the inserts being added to a shard (and to multiple shards after the migration threshold was reached).  Hope it helps others